# wxpython self made widget and drag and drop it in a canvas

Tags: wxpython

I want to build an app for making UML diagrams. For visibility problems, I wish I could move classes using the mouse.

So here is my problem :

Do you know how can I drag and drop a widget in a canvas using wxPython ?
Found some things about ogl, but sound strange to me ...

Thx guys

Comment: Haven't you come across with [this example](https://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FloatCanvas sample in the wxPython demo.  There is also a sample for the OGL package there.  Either, or both of those would likely be suitable for diagrams depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks you, i'll look at those during the week !